# While using static dictionary ,i got an error "Item has already been added." in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary

When i debug code with f10 IT WORKS with NO ERROR !.But on runtime i got this error:
"An item with the same key has already been added"

Plz help

My Dictionary :

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> ImageFilePath
        = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Using in same Glob.cs my function :

```
public static Image ShowImageOnColumn(string Value,byte ImageHeigth,byte ImageWidth)
{

   .
   .
   .

    string FilePath = "",ImgId = "";


    Image img_ = new Image();

    Random rnd = new Random();

    ImgId = rnd.Next(100000000).ToString();
    img_.ImageUrl = "ShowImageInRuntime.aspx?FileName=" + ImgId;

    ImageFilePath.Add(ImgId, FilePath);


    img_.Height = Unit.Pixel(ImageHeigth);
    img_.Width = Unit.Pixel(ImageWidth);

    return img_;

   }
```

Comment: A Dictionary cannot contain duplicate keys and your Random generates duplicate `ImgId`s.

Comment: Put messagebox before 'add' show there all items with sort and run your app. I think there are realy dublicate items

Comment: Try replacing the random generation code with `Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not guarding your `ImageFilePath.Add` call. If the key already exists, you will get an exception saying as much.

You can do a check for a key:

```
if (ImageFilePath.ContainsKey(ImgId))
{
    ImageFilePath[ImgId] = FilePath;
}
```

Or you can set on the index, this will add if it's missing and update if it exists:

```
ImageFilePath[ImgId] = FilePath;
```

As opposed to calling Add.

Note, however, that static members are **liable to being lost** when IIS recycles worker processes. Hence they tend to be avoided. There are also multi-threading issues as the static member is visible across the process.

If you need a random file name, try `DateTime.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmssfff")` or `Guid.NewGuid()`, as opposed to keeping an instance of `Random` alive.

`Path` also features a `GetTempFileName` method.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you instantiate `Random` class every time you use the funciton and restart the random seed.
Instantiate the `Random` in a singleton, probably in the class constructor and you'll have a valid uniq(ish) number every time you call.

I would suggest also, that random is not unique, for a unique value you most probably want to use a hash algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")` instead of Random number. This would ensure there is no collision. Also, give a thought process regarding usage of static members. They are shared across multiple threads and you might run into thread safety issues when multiple users access your site at same time.

Comment: Guid is not unique also, and can be less unique than Random. Try inserting 1-10 million GUIDs into a dictionary and you'll see... self correction: Guid.GetHash() is what is not unique

Comment: @PeterAronZentai Guid might not be "unique" but it has a hell of a lot more values available than int.

Comment: @Peter Aron Zentai `Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")` is generating 32 digit value. So How can it be duplicate? If i start generating till 10 million only.

Comment: Guid collision probability is very less. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates

Comment: As I corrected myself: the hash of guids are not unique as could be expected from a hash function.

Comment: @mennan - there is a serious flaw in your approach. The dictionary is going to be keep on adding entries for every call and will eventually run out of memory. Check your other question you posted for a better sample code.

Comment: @PeterAronZentai I agree you self corrected. But would like to bring to your attention that there is still a chance of collision but its probability is very very less or negligible :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the Key already exists or not before adding the Key to the dictionary

```
if (!ImageFilePath.ContainsKey(ImgId))                     
{
    ImageFilePath.Add(ImgId,FilePath); 
}
```